# Unable to get exact time difference of two time stamps in android

Tags: android, jodatime

As I mentioned I am not getting the difference of two time stamps.I have to calculate the duration of flights.The code that I have done so far is

```
 public static void jodaDifference()
{
    String departure= "2016-05-3122:05:00";
    String arrival=  "2016-06-0107:35:00";
    //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
            DateTimeFormatter format =  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-ddHH:mm:ss");

            DateTime d1 = null;
            DateTime d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parseDateTime(departure);
        d2 = format.parseDateTime(arrival);

    Duration duration = new Duration(d1, d2);
    System.out.println(duration.getStandardDays());
    System.out.println(duration.getStandardHours());
    System.out.println(duration.getStandardMinutes());

      System.out.print(Days.daysBetween(d1, d2).getDays() + " days, ");
      System.out.print(Hours.hoursBetween(d1, d2).getHours() % 24 + " hours, ");
      System.out.print(Minutes.minutesBetween(d1, d2).getMinutes() % 60 + " minutes, ");
      System.out.print(Seconds.secondsBetween(d1, d2).getSeconds() % 60 + " seconds."); 

      final Period period = new Period(d1, d2);
      System.out.print(period.getDays() + " days, ");
      System.out.print(period.getHours() + " hours, ");
      System.out.print(period.getMinutes() + " minutes, ");
      System.out.print(period.getSeconds() + " seconds.");

    System.out.println(""+Days.daysBetween(d1.withTimeAtStartOfDay(), d2.withTimeAtStartOfDay()).getDays());  

}catch(Exception ex)
{

}

}
```

Output:

```
30
-734
-44070
-30 days, -14 hours, -30 minutes, 0 seconds.-2 days, -14 hours,-30 minutes,0 seconds.-30
```

This code calculating wrong difference for some time stamps and working perfect for the others.Please help me...

Comment: In my opinion the easiest way to calculate durations is to get timestamps and just do a substraction of two longs

Comment: I already do that,but does not work for me.

Comment: Can you give examples of what inputs are giving you issues and what is the expected output?

Comment: Input are:String departure= "2016-05-3122:05:00";
String arrival=  "2016-06-0107:35:00"; and the expected output is 9hrs 30 mins

Answer (score 0):

At least your pattern is wrong because you have to use the symbol "M" for months while "m" stands for the minute-of-hour.

Another thing about representation of durations with multiple units: Joda-Time offers the classes `Period` and `PeriodFormatter` for this purpose. Using your home-grown logic to build multi-unit-durations (called periods in Joda-Time) is errorprone and surprisingly awkward. Let Joda-Time do this job for you.

Solution in Joda-Time:

```
String departure = "2016-05-3122:05:00";
String arrival = "2016-06-0107:35:00";

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime ldt1 = f.parseLocalDateTime(departure);
LocalDateTime ldt2 = f.parseLocalDateTime(arrival);
Period p = new Period(ldt1, ldt2, PeriodType.dayTime());

System.out.println("Hour part: " + p.getHours()); // 9
System.out.println("Minute part: " + p.getMinutes()); // 30

System.out.println(PeriodFormat.wordBased(Locale.ENGLISH).print(p));
// output: 9 hours and 30 minutes
```

This works for about 13 languages. Short forms of units like "hrs" or "mins" are not directly supported unless you are willing to use `PeriodFormatterBuilder` and fixed literals (limited to one language only).

Comment: @S.Jain Side note: My answer represents a simplified view just for zoneless timestamps (like your input). Since flight times are usually given as "local" timestamps in different time zones you should probably apply a timezone calculation, too IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a lot Meno!!